# Average of calculated field in Access subform

Tags: ms-access, average, calculated-field, subform

I am working in Access 2007 with a subform that shows the Mass of a determined set of records linked to a master form.
The form is displayed in spreadsheet view and has two columns `[Mass]` and `[Include]`. `Include` is a True/False field to select whether the record is to be included in the final calculation.

In the footer of the subform, I want to add the average of the masses of the records where `[Include] = True`.
So far I have created a new field `[MassIF] = IIf([Include]=True,[Mass],Null)`, this works correctly in the spreadsheet.

However, the `=Avg([MassIF])` control in the footer gives an error, any idea why that would be and how to get around the issue?

Also, `=Avg([Mass])` works fine until I add to the footer the `=Avg([MassIF])` control, then I get `#ERROR` in both fields, which looks really odd to me.

Comment: You mean Datasheet View? Datasheet View does not show header and footer sections so where are you displaying this Avg calc? By 'new field' do you mean a textbox? Aggregate calcs cannot reference controls, must be fields in RecordSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calculation in textbox in footer:

=Avg(IIf([Include], [Mass], Null))